# InfluxDB: High cardinality for specific shards

Tags: influxdb

I'm querying data from different shards and used `EXPLAIN` to check how many series are being fetched for that particular date range.

```
> SHOW SHARDS
.
.
658 mydb autogen          658         2019-07-22T00:00:00Z 2019-07-29T00:00:00Z 2020-07-27T00:00:00Z
676 mydb autogen          676         2019-07-29T00:00:00Z 2019-08-05T00:00:00Z 2020-08-03T00:00:00Z
.
.
```

Executing `EXPLAIN` for data from shard **658** and it's giving expected result in terms of number of series. `SensorId` is only tag key and as date range fall into only shard it's giving `NUMBER OF SERIES: 1`

```
> EXPLAIN select "kWh" from Reading where (SensorId =~ /^1186$/) AND time >= '2019-07-27 00:00:00' AND time <= '2019-07-28 00:00:00' limit 10;
QUERY PLAN
----------
EXPRESSION: <nil>
AUXILIARY FIELDS: "kWh"::float
NUMBER OF SHARDS: 1
NUMBER OF SERIES: 1
CACHED VALUES: 0
NUMBER OF FILES: 2
NUMBER OF BLOCKS: 4
SIZE OF BLOCKS: 32482
```

But when I run the same query on date range that falls into **shard 676**, number of series is 13140 instead of just one.

```
> EXPLAIN select "kWh" from Reading where (SensorId =~ /^1186$/) AND time >= '2019-07-29 00:00:00' AND time < '2019-07-30 00:00:00';
QUERY PLAN
----------
EXPRESSION: <nil>
AUXILIARY FIELDS: "kWh"::float
NUMBER OF SHARDS: 1
NUMBER OF SERIES: 13140
CACHED VALUES: 0
NUMBER OF FILES: 11426
NUMBER OF BLOCKS: 23561
SIZE OF BLOCKS: 108031642
```

**Environment info:**

- System info: Linux 4.4.0-1087-aws x86_64
- InfluxDB version: InfluxDB v1.7.6 (git: 1.7 [01c8dd4](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/commit/01c8dd416270f424ab0c40f9291e269ac6921964))

**Update - 1**

On checking field cardinality, I observed a spike in RAM.

```
> SHOW FIELD KEY CARDINALITY
```

**Update - 2**

I've rebuilt the indexes, but the cardinality is still high.

**Update - 3**

I found out that shard has "SensorId" as tag as well as field that causing high cardinality when querying with the "SensorId" filter.

```
> SELECT COUNT("SensorId") from Reading GROUP BY "SensorId";
name: Reading
tags: SensorId=
time                 count
----                 -----
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 40
```

But when I'm checking tag values with key 'SensorId', it's not showing empty string that present in the above query.

```
> show tag values with key = "SensorId"
name: Reading
key      value
---      -----
SensorId 10034
SensorId 10037
SensorId 10038
SensorId 10039
SensorId 10040
SensorId 10041
.
.
.
SensorId 9938
SensorId 9939
SensorId 9941
SensorId 9942
SensorId 9944
SensorId 9949
```

**Update - 4**

Inspected data using `influx_inspect dumptsm` and re-validated that null tag values are present

```
$ influx_inspect dumptsm -index -filter-key "" /var/lib/influxdb/data/mydb/autogen/235/000008442-000000013.tsm

Index:

  Pos   Min Time                Max Time                Ofs     Size    Key                     Field
  1     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    5       103     Reading                 1001
  2     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    108     275     Reading                 2001
  3     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    383     248     Reading                 2002
  4     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    631     278     Reading                 2003
  5     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    909     278     Reading                 2004
  6     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    1187    184     Reading                 2005
  7     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    1371    103     Reading                 2006
  8     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    1474    250     Reading                 2007
  9     2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    1724    103     Reading                 2008
  10    2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    1827    275     Reading                 2012
  11    2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    2102    416     Reading                 2101
  12    2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    2518    103     Reading                 2692
  13    2019-08-01T01:46:31Z    2019-08-01T17:42:03Z    2621    101     Reading                 SensorId
  14    2019-07-29T00:00:05Z    2019-07-29T05:31:07Z    2722    1569    Reading,SensorId=10034  2005
  15    2019-07-29T05:31:26Z    2019-07-29T11:03:54Z    4291    1467    Reading,SensorId=10034  2005
  16    2019-07-29T11:04:14Z    2019-07-29T17:10:16Z    5758    1785    Reading,SensorId=10034  2005
```

Comment: If you need reducing RAM usage for high number of time series, then take a look at another time series databases such as TimescaleDB or VictoriaMetrics. See [this article](https://medium.com/@valyala/insert-benchmarks-with-inch-influxdb-vs-victoriametrics-e31a41ae2893), which compares RAM usage for InfluxDB and VictoriaMetrics for various cardinality levels

Comment: It's not about high number of time-series, it's a bug that showing two different series-cardinality in different shards (having equal distribution of data).